# Use a person's name to create a unique, non-reversible ID

Tags: encryption, cryptography, statistics

Is there a way (an algorithm) to take someone's name (first name and surname) and turn it into a unique, non-reversible ID? I know I could just start at unique id = 1 and just add one. I was wondering if there was a way that I could generate IDs using someone's name.

I'm just after a pointer to the way to do it and I'll code it myself.

Comment: Using a Cryptographic hash function is a way, but there is a negligible change of collisions that one can overcome.

Comment: How will you make one "Jane Smith" different from another "Jane Smith"?  Your input, (first name and surname) is not unique, so you will need something else to make the output unique. Something like: Jane Smith 1, Jane Smith 2, Jane Smith 3... would work, but needs more record keeping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for is called a *hash function*.  Hash functions will always produce the same fixed-length output for a given input.

For non-cryptographic endeavours, SHA256 is often a good choice.  It will produce a 256-bit output and is available natively in most standard libraries.

Comment: But hash functions can have collisions which is absolutely contrary to the idea of an ID...

Comment: @Ben373 Practically speaking, you are so incredibly unlikely to find a collision in a 256-bit space that you can very safely ignore the implications of a collision. You might be interested in UUIDs/GUIDs, which are only 128 bits in length and are still considered unique.

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

You say you want to generate a non-reversible ID from a name. While you *can* generate an ID from a name, this will always be reversible. That is because there is not enough information in a name.

Consider that any name is chosen from a set of 7 billion names (that's how many people there are), then the maximum possible Shannon entropy of an ID is about 32.7 bits. In other words, it will take about 2^32.7 tries before you have tried all names on Earth. For a computer, that's easy.

For example, if we would create the IDs by hashing with SHA256, as Luke Joshua Park [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54645847/5207081), we can easily find the name corresponding to an ID using a regular brute force attack. My laptop needs only 0.5µs to compute a SHA256 hash. So to find the IDs off *all* humans on earth, I would need less than an hour if I use a somewhat beefy CPU.

Comment: ...except to do this you need to actually *know* the names of all 7 billion people on the planet.  I'd argue that you probably don't.  This opens up the input space by a non-trivial amount.  We can also extend this out to 2^32.7 computations **per hash you test** by using a salt.  Theoretically you're completely right but practically this is a non-issue.